# Creating a string argument with a function parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pyspark, graphframes

I am trying to create a function that will allow a user to perform a Breadth-first-search in Graphframes using the .bfs method.  An example function looks like:

```
    Graphframe.bfs("name = 'Esther'", "relationship = 'friend'")
```

I would like a function to work like:

```
    def friendZone(person, affiliation):
         Graphframe.bfs("name = 'person'", "relationship = 'affiliation'")
```

I have tried using a concat method like:

```
     '"' + "name='" + person + "'" + '"'
```

, but that has not worked. I also tried using

```
'"name={}"'.format(person).
```

Help please?

Comment: What went wrong with the things you tried?

Comment: It just didn't produce the result I needed for the arguments.  Sometimes I would end up with backslashes in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an f-string

```
def friendZone(person, affiliation):
         Graphframe.bfs(f"name = {person}", "relationship = {affiliation}")
```

Comment: Thank you!  This didn't specifically fix my problem, but it did lead me to the solution.  I ended up using "name='%s'"% person, which worked perfectly.